# How to remove widget from kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, widgets

I am using Kubuntu, I added a new widget in desktop screen will show my RAM usage by different types of applications. But now I want to remove that widget but I am not able to remove it. (to remove any widget, we have to just press mouse right button and it will show options to remove the widget). But now nothing is happening when I press mouse right button.
If I add another widget, I am able to remove it. The problem is only with that widget.

I tried `xkill` command to kill that widget, but it is killing my desktop screen and screen turns into black color. So I restart my computer and that widget is still in my desktop screen.  You can see my [widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u2Ga.jpg) given in image on right side.

**Note** : That widget is working fine, but I want to remove it.

**How to remove that widget ?**

Comment: Can you remove it after entering edit mode?

Comment: Thanks, now I am able to remove it after entering in edit mode.

Comment: I am new to Kubuntu. My friends said it is more customizable and has a lot of features.

Comment: Yes, the KDE Plasma desktop in Kubuntu is heavily customizable. You may find some nice youtube videos with detailed descriptions.

Comment: Sure, I will check those videos.